# substr with japanese characters issue

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

i'm echoing japanese characters fine but when i try to substr and echo out part of the string it just turn to question marks ���

note: i set my header to utf-8

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

and made the meta 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

```
$word = "せんせい";
echo $word;       //works just fine

echo substr($word,-1);    //now it just echoes �

//this one also failed
echo $word[0];    //echoes �
```

Comment: Please understand what the header does, it simply makes a claim that the content you give is encoded in `UTF-8`. Which it is not because `substr` mutilates the bytes to invalid `UTF-8`

Answer (score 10):

When working with your multibyte strings, you'll need to use the [`multibyte string`](http://php.net/mbstring) functions, in this case [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php).

Comment: @N.B. sorry to have offended you so.

Comment: With all my might, I will find strength to forgive and forget.

Answer (score 3):

Try multibyte substrings, mb_substr() info found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) This function is made for characters not in the english ascii code set.

Answer (score 2):

```
mb_substr
```

will work. But, remember to add the following line at the top of your script:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");//Sets the internal character encoding to UTF-8, for mb_substr to work
```